# React - synchronous txt file to string?

Tags: reactjs, text, create-react-app

I'm absolutely baffled by this one...

In my React project with create-react-app, I have a standalone `js` file in which I'd like to read a string from a `txt` file.  The `txt` file is part of a project and not on a server.

I can't seem to find any answers of how to complete this seemingly trivial task in a synchronous manner.  These would seem like obvious options:

```
import text from './data/text.txt';

const text = require('./data/text.txt');
```

Both lines above return a new path that includes `/static/media/`, which I can access through localhost in the browser, but that doesn't help me.

I can use JSON but it's almost a matter of principle at this point.  It just seems ridiculous that I can't read a simple txt file.

Comment: It is not a trivial task in react (a client side library). You should have a input with type `file` and then use `FileReader` object or `Blob` to read content of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use webpack [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) to directly import raw files into your project.

Install:

```
$ npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Config:

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.txt$/i,
        use: 'raw-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Usage:

```
import text from './data/text.txt';
console.log(text);  // This line will print out the content of the text file in the console
```